# Magento 2 - add image to Downloadable Products table in Account Area

Tags: magento2, downloadable

What is the best way to add the base product image next to the product name within the downloadable products table that shows in a user's account area?

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the downloadable links list template in your custom theme. You should create file `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/Magento_Downloadable/templates/customer/products/list.phtml` with the following content:

```
<?php

use Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\Purchased\Item;

/**
 * @var $block \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Customer\Products\ListProducts
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer
 */

$objectManager = Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository */
$productRepository = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository::class);

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper */
$imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class);
?>
<?php $_items = $block->getItems(); ?>
<?php if (count($_items)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper downloadable-products">
        <table id="my-downloadable-products-table" class="data table table-downloadable-products">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Downloadable Products')) ?></caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Title')) ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col remaining"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Remaining Downloads')) ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php /** @var \Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\Purchased\Item $_item */ ?>
            <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getOrderViewUrl($_item->getPurchased()->getOrderId()))?>"
                           title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('View Order')) ?>">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getOrderIncrementId()) ?>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->formatDate($_item->getPurchased()->getCreatedAt())) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Title')) ?>" class="col title">
                        <?php
                        try {
                            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
                            $product = $productRepository->getById($_item->getProductId());
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                            $product = false;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php if ($product): ?>
                        <div class="product-image">
                            <img src="<?= $imageHelper->init($product, 'category_page_grid')->resize(100, 100)->getUrl(); ?>" />
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <strong class="product-name">
                            <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?>
                        </strong>
                        <?php if ($_item->getStatus() == Item::LINK_STATUS_AVAILABLE): ?>
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getDownloadUrl($_item)) ?>"
                               id="download_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_item->getPurchased()->getProductId() ?>"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Start Download')) ?>"
                               class="action download">
                                <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()) ?>
                            </a>
                            <?php if ($block->getIsOpenInNewWindow()): ?>
                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderEventListenerAsTag(
                                    'onclick',
                                    "this.target='_blank'",
                                    'a#download_' . $_item->getPurchased()->getProductId()
                                ) ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml(__(ucfirst($_item->getStatus()))) ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Remaining Downloads')) ?>" class="col remaining">
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getRemainingDownloads($_item)) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getChildHtml('pager')): ?>
        <div class="toolbar downloadable-products-toolbar bottom">
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('pager') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty">
        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You have not purchased any downloadable products yet.')) ?></span>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="secondary">
        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>" class="action back">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Back')) ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this!  Is there a way to do it via a module / extending the block so ObjectManager isn't required?